# How to check if a function is done and then call another function

Tags: angular, typescript, methods, angular6

I need to check if a user has selected form ngFor a item and then redirect to another page when submitting the form with the new value.

HTML:

```
<mat-select placeholder="Tratament" [(ngModel)]="model.TratamentA" name="TratamentA" #TratamentA (change)="onChange(TratamentA.value)"
 disableRipple>
    <mat-option value="Sutent (Sunitinibum) 25mg">Sutent (Sunitinibum) 25mg</mat-option>
    <mat-option value="Sutent (Sunitinibum) 37.5mg">Sutent (Sunitinibum) 37.5mg</mat-option>
    <mat-option value="Sutent (Sunitinibum) 50mg">Sutent (Sunitinibum) 50mg</mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

---

```
<div class="row">
            <button mat-raised-button color="primary" type="submit" value="submit">Update Patient</button>
            <button mat-raised-button color="accent" (click)="goBack()">Anulare</button>
          </div>
```

TS

```
private onChange(TratamentAValue): any {
    console.log(TratamentAValue);
}

onChangeSubmit(){
    const CONDITION = true;
    const DATA = this.onChange(this.TratamentAValue);
    const ERROR = new Error(this.goBack())

    const promise =
        new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            // do some async stuff
            this.router.navigate(['/pacient/ra', this.id]);

            if (CONDITION) resolve(DATA);
            else reject(ERROR);
        })

    updatePacient() {
        this.pacService
            .updatePacient(this.model)
            .subscribe(() => this.onChangeSubmit());

    }
  model = new Pacient();
  id = this.route.snapshot.params['id'];
  private getSinglePacient(): any {
    this.pacService
        .getPacient(this.id)
        .subscribe(pacient => {
          this.model = pacient[0];
        })
  }
    }
```

To keep it short, i need to check if a value has changed, for a certain field, and then redirect the user to desired component. It always redirect to ['/pacient/ra', this.id]); I need to redirect de user only if selected a new treatment from the list. All this activity showld start when submitting the form...

Answer (score 0):

You can keep your original and changed values into separate variabiles, for example

```
originalTratament: any;
newTratament: any;
```

Then in your `onChange()` you can set new value like follows:

```
private onChange(TratamentAValue): any {
    this.newTratament = TratamentAValue;
}
```

At last you can compare your variables to check they are different:

```
onChangeSubmit(){
    const CONDITION = this.originalTratament != this.newTratament;
    const DATA = this.onChange(this.TratamentAValue);
    const ERROR = new Error(this.goBack())

    const promise =
        new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            // do some async stuff
            this.router.navigate(['/pacient/ra', this.id]);

            if (CONDITION) resolve(DATA);
            else reject(ERROR);
        })

    updatePacient() {
        this.pacService
            .updatePacient(this.model)
            .subscribe(() => this.onChangeSubmit());

    }
}
```

You may change something because I don't know your data structures

Comment: Thank you so much for your effort, but is still not working, i am so close. Is still redirecting to (this.goBack()), and not redirecting to /pacient/ra, after submiting the new value... I think the DATA is not resolved somehow. The thing is, that the user that change the treatment when submitting the form, must redirect to SideEffects page. Everything is working fine on the api and all...

Comment: Got an error: Uncaught (in promise): [object Undefined] when submit without selecting newTreatment.